# Eagle Why ground pour is not connected to smd pads of components in a Module

Tags: pcb, pcb-design, circuit-design, eaglecad

I have created modules in my schematics, the Gnd pads of components in main schematics are connected to ground pour and does not have air wires.
But SMD pads of components in the module have sir wires and are not connected to ground pour? Why is this happening ?

[image: DC/DC is the module name and the GND pin has air wires and not connected to pour]

What I tried:
1) In the module schematics I have GND port and I connected it to GND pin in main sheet. still didn't help.
And thoughts are welcome , Thanks:)

[image: DC/DC GND is connected to main GND in main sheet]

Comment: Its difficult to see with the PCB image zoomed in but it looks like your ground pour could be on a different net to the SMD component. Its also worth checking your design rules as you may have an edge case setup for SMD pads

Comment: Don't forget to use the NAME tool and click on the polygon pour outline. Name the net "GND" to make sure it has the same net as the "GND" in the schematic.

Comment: Check your net classes - perhaps  the trace width for GND is defined as being too wide for the part you are connecting to.  Altho I like not having Named the polygon used for GND as well.

Comment: I really don't understand what's wrong with your layout – this is a two-pad component. The only two-pad component in your schematic is your diode. That is not connected to ground. Your two-pad component is not connected to ground but has a yellow airwire where you've not yet connected it.

Comment: Did you name your ground pour "DC/DC: GND" instead of just "GND"? Try picking up the component in the schematic editor and see if it really is connected, sometimes Eagle has floating nets/components that look connected but really aren't.

Comment: voting to close this as unclear since OP has gone mute :(

Comment: AndyWest DerStrom8 CrossRoards:  Yes the polygon is named to GND and i tried to adjust the width of the traces, did not help.

Comment: @RonBeyer  Thanks , yes it was because of improper connection. i found out when i ran ERC. There was an overlap in Net GND with the Port.

Answer (score 1):

I dont know how I managed to place the port in between the dots in the sheet.[image]

So there was no proper connection between the GND and the port , found it when I did ERC.

Thanks a lot for your time!!